# Pasar valores de un listbox a un textbox

Tags: c#, html5, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente problema, quisiera pasar un valor de un listbox concatenado a una base de datos a un textbox, pero en mi codigo no funciona ello.

Uso VS 2019

Codigo cs

```
namespace User_Login_CS
{
    public partial class usuariossistemas : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public DataTable CargarDatos()
        {
            string str = "Data Source=IP; Initial Catalog=iLogistica; Persist Security Info=True; user id=USER; password=PASS;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string com = "SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[UsuariosSistema] ORDER BY Nombre ";
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "UsuariosSistema");
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
            return myDataTable;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dt = CargarDatos();
                foreach (DataRow fila in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(fila[0] + " (" + fila[1] + ") (" + fila[2] + ")");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable tabla = CargarDatos();
            int indice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice]["Nombre"]);
        }
    }

}
```

Codigo ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="usuariossistemas.aspx.cs" Inherits="User_Login_CS.usuariossistemas" %>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" class="form-control listadenombres" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>          
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:TextBox class="form-control nombresyapellidos" ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

A ver si me hechan una ayuda.

Saludos !

pd. Saben de algun emulador para estos codigos tipo jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi error, lo había tratado como un DataGridView, prueba agregando el .ToString()
Prueba cambiando esta funcion:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DataTable tabla = CargarDatos();
            int indice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice]["Nombre"]);
}
```

por esta:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DataTable tabla = CargarDatos();
            int indice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
            TextBox1.Text = CargarDatos().Rows[indice ]["Nombre"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: .cells ? no creo que esa sea la respuesta.

Comment: Cierto, perdón lo había tomado como DataGridView, si cambias de funcion de Button1_Click por listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: No me funciono, ni con la solucion ni cambiando a SelectedIndexChanged, ando viendo en donde puede estar el error.

Comment: Si quieres podrías enviarme el proyecto para checarlo con mayor detalle, estás seguro que la consulta si te está dando datos?

Comment: Hace dos horas habia acabado de arreglar ello, me sirvio tu referencia con respecto al "SelectedIndexChange", me olvidé poner el valor en el ListBox " OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" "
Muchas gracias.